# Design for table with multiple links to other table

Tags: database-design, schema, relational-theory

I am designing a database to keep track of our network equipment. My db has 2 tables:

sites & circuits

(circuit = cable) & (site = property location)

Each circuit runs between two sites, so it should relate to two sites, yes? The circuit table has the following  columns: `ID_circuit (PK), circuit_number, site1, site2`. I thought that I could relate my `ID_site` field to both `site1` and `site2`, but I cannot. Would I be better off creating a whole other table to hold the locations of both cable ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site1 and site2 can both be FKs, linked to the ID_site PK. This works on any rdbms that i'm aware of.

Example Query:

```
SELECT CT.site1, CT.site2, S1.site_description, S2.site_description
FROM circuit_table AS CT
INNER JOIN site_table as S1
  ON CT.site1 = S1.ID_site
INNER JOIN site_table as S2
  ON CT.site2 = S2.ID_site
```

Comment: How would I then query this to get information on both of the sites? If I use a `LEFT JOIN`, I only get circuit info, if I `RIGHT JOIN`, I only get site info, if I `INNER JOIN`, I don't get anything.

Comment: edited answer with example query

Comment: If you think of the two sites differently e.g. one is a "source" and the other is a "destination" make sure you name the foreign key columns appropriately and put the right `id_site` in the right column.  If you think of them symetrically be aware of this.  The combination (A,B) will be the same in your mind as (B,A) but will be a different value as far as the table is concerned.  You need to look out for this when writing data and queries.

Comment: I'm using MS Access (I know), so the query I ended up using is `SELECT CT.cableName, S1.siteName, S2.siteName
FROM (cables AS CT INNER JOIN sites AS S1 ON CT.site1 = S1.idSite) INNER JOIN sites AS S2 ON CT.site2 = S2.idSite;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be better off creating a whole separate table to hold the locations of both cable ends **unless you can enforce constraints during  row creation**. The ambiguity mentioned by [Michael Green](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/36809/michael-green) in [a comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71296/design-for-table-with-multiple-links-to-other-table/71298#71298), about how one ensures that AB is recognized as identical to BA, is the critical issue.

If you are in a position to enforce an ordering constraint on the sites during row construction then the issue is less significant, and you can take the shortcut of a single table safely.

If you require the separate Site table, you will probably wish to add a **bit** field such as **IsSource** to its Key as the simplest way to ensure that each Circuit can have only 2 ends.

Comment: The problem with making an IsSource column is that each site could have multiple circuits going to it. I can enforce constraints, and Rydel's query works fine.

Comment: @NateMara: If you are in control of the creation process then I agree - that solution is simpler. Just be aware of the issues and ambiguities involved.

Comment: This is all in an Access DB (I know it's bad; I'm just a lowly intern, have to listen to boss), so everyone using the DB will have to use my forms to fill data, and I can ensure that they only use valid info.